# Not able to get current View from Android native (Java) when used in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-layout

I have my own Android SDK/library where I get the user's current view using `_window.getDecorView()` to get an image of that view using **below code** and it's working fine in Android Native.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
v.draw(canvas);
```

But when I use this library in a Flutter app (via a Flutter plugin), I am getting only **white image**.